# Blog has oldish spam comments

Tags: support, blog

FYI, I noticed that [the penultimate blog post](http://diy.blogoverflow.com/2013/04/replumbing-an-improper-trap/) has 3 spam comments that have been there for a month or more. Someone with the access to do so should delete them.

Comment: Looking over the comments, there are a lot of posts that are "thank you, great information" with their name linked to a site they are promoting. Should those be considered spam, trash, or allowed? I unapproved a bunch of them so others could make a judgment call.

Comment: I usually remove the site links from comments (would be nice if this "feature" could be turned off), but I haven't had much time to spend on the blog lately.

Answer (score 1):

The [blog](http://diy.blogoverflow.com/) is dead, and nobody cares about it anymore (not sure they ever did).

[image]

Comment: I did. I'll try and blog about fence building this weekend.